# Compare list to multiple other lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, compare

I've not had any luck searching for a solution to this, partly because I'm not exactly sure how best to explain the problem! Hopefully I'm clear here but if not please feel free to ask for more info.

At the top level:
In our database, each customer can have multiple services. Services are allocated to a customer individually. However, we need 'group' services into 'packages' of common service combinations for reporting purposes.

I have a database which contains package definitions - a table called packageServices, simply listing each PackageID with an associated ServiceID. Therefore I can retrieve a list of services for each package.

From the same database I can retrieve a list of ServiceIDs for a particular customer.

What I am trying to accomplish is to compare the list of ServiceIDs retrieved for that customer, and see if that combination matches any of the defined pacakges (i.e. combinations of ServiceIDs) and if so report which package(s) that customer has.

I'm struggling to know where to begin so far as the comparison goes! I guess I need to start by creating some sort of list of serviceIDs for each package (rather than my current KeyValuePairs (in the dictionary) with multiple lines for each package?) then iterate through the packages and compare those lists of services with the list of services that customer has?

The data types used here may not be most appropriate - in many cases I'm referring to a 'logical' list rather than a C# List object - I can use whichever datatype is appropriate :)

Any help much appreciated!

**EDIT** - It's been suggested that I collate this information in SQL instead of in my C# application. This seems like a good idea and one of the answers below has brought me close. However, there are 'business rules' in place which determine whether a package is an 'upgrade' of a lower package or a package in itself and this is seriously complicating things.

The more I try to make this work the more I think that I've bitten off more than I can chew! I am *trying* to design this properly, so that any changes to services or packages in the future will be handled easily - these changes are unlikely but possible. However, it would be much easier to just to hardcode the options from what I've seen so far!

**EDIT 2** - I've been working through this and it has been suggested that I assign a 'weight' and a 'group' to each package. The groups are there to ensure that a customer can only have one package from each group, and the weights are there to ensure that only the 'highest' level package is returned. Using this in conjunction with @MarceloCantos 's query will mean that I should be able to return just the 'highest' weight package from each group - this looks like it might fit the requirements of the application!

Thanks to all who have helped so far - I'm amazed how quickly the responses started coming in and at the quality of the responses given. I'll give this a go and see how I get on.

Comment: What kind of size numbers are we talking about for services, packages, typical packages per service, and so on?

Comment: @AakashM - Good point. Services and packages will always be relatively small - currently 7 services arranges into 8 packages - this will grow but not significantly. So far, max number of services per package is 6. Number of customers will grow into the thousands. However these 'calculations' only have to be performed once a month.

Comment: Is this a 'once off' job to work out which packages each customer has, or do you need to do it everything time someone visits the site? It would make more sense, as Dave suggests below, to store the data in your database - work it out once, today, and then make sure it's updated and you never have to work it out again.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst - Essentially this only needs to happen once a month - we'll retrieve a list of all customers and which package they are on, for our own use, and a total list of the number of customers on each package, for our supplier to use to bill us. Packages change on a monthly basis depending on which services a customer has - the customer buys individual services but we are billed for 'packages' from the supplier, unfortunately!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the services for the customer and then, for each package that has the same number of services, count the services that match the customer's services. Only an exact match will yield the same count.

You can do this in a single query, albeit a rather tricksy one:

```
SELECT CustomerID, PackageID
  FROM (SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(*) AS qty
          FROM customerServices
         GROUP BY CustomerID
       ) cs
  JOIN (SELECT PackageID, COUNT(*) AS qty
          FROM packageServices
         GROUP BY PackageID
       ) ps ON cs.qty = ps.qty
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM customerServices cs2
          JOIN packageServices ps2 ON cs2.ServiceID = ps2.ServiceID
         WHERE cs2.CustomerID = cs.CustomerID
           AND ps2.PackageID = ps.PackageID
       ) = ps.qty
```

**EDIT:** Perhaps I misunderstood the question. If you want to find packages that contain a *subset* of the customer's services, you can do this instead:

```
 ...
       ) ps ON cs.qty >= ps.qty -- Change the test
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM customerServices cs2
          JOIN packageServices ps2 ON cs2.ServiceID = ps2.ServiceID
         WHERE cs2.CustomerID = cs.CustomerID
           AND ps2.PackageID = ps.PackageID
       ) = ps.qty
```

**EDIT 2:** I changed the logic of the second case to exploit the fact that if the intersection of two sets is the same size as the smaller set, then the smaller set is a subset of the larger.

Comment: he'll have to do that for each package that has <= number of services as the client

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos - many thanks - I think you've understood the problem well despite me explaining it badly! You're quite right, the customer could have additional services not part of the package. Let me think through your solution in detail and report back but doing it in SQL makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @JimmE: NP. BTW, I've changed the logic. I realised that you can still use the set-counting approach — thus avoiding the double-NOT-EXISTS mess — when testing for subsets.

Comment: @Bond: Thanks for pointing that out. I've amended the answer.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst: I'm not sure what you're getting at (or whether my recent amendments address your comment or not). I've tested both version with sample data sets and they work correctly, but perhaps I've missed something.

Comment: @MarceloCantos - Edit: Many thanks. One thing I didn't make clear is that some packages 'extend' others - i.e. Package1 contains Service1 and Service2. Package2 contains Service1, Service2 and Service3. If Customer1 has Services 1, 2 and 3, your query returns both Package 1 and Package 2 (which I can understand). We only consider them to have the one package - Package 2 (as it is the 'best' fit). I'll have a go at making some modifications to your query and see how I get on! Apologies again for not explaining the situation clearly!

Answer (score 3):

i'd recommend that you not try to compute on the fly the packages to which a customer is subscribed (subscribed is probably not the right word, but you know what i mean).  i'd suggest you keep separate records indicating the packages to which a customer is subscribed in the database.  every time a customer adds a new service, you use a message indicating the event of adding a service has occurred and handle that event by updating the packages for that customer with any packages that are now complete with the addition of the new product.

Comment: many thanks - To a certain extent I agree. I didn't want to go into too much detail on the business reasons for it being this way as I didn't want to bore you all - but it seems to be relevant to the reason I think we need to calculate this on the fly.

Comment: boring or not, the business reasons are probably off-topic here.  hard for me to imagine business requirements that would dictate that you can't do some denormalization, but you certainly know your domain better than i do.  without this, you probably want to let the database handle the crunching of the sets as marcelo suggested, as rdbms are built for this.  an alternative to crafting sql by hand would be to use an orm with a linq provider and express the queries in linq.  i fear you'll have problems with scale with this approach, though.  maybe you don't care about scale, so it might work.

Comment: i'd also suggest that the perception that business rules are dictating technical solutions could mean that you are making some assumptions about what the business really requires that may or may not be valid or that business is pushing technical solutions on you which is something you should resist if you can.  it might be worth revisiting the requirements to see if you can decide that maybe they are not really expressing the intent of the business.